# Simple Random Password Generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I've made a password generator that works fine. It takes alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation characters and randomly generates a 8-16 character password.

```
import sys
import string
import random

def PasswordGenerator():
    Name = input("What is your name? ")
    if Name.isalpha():
        GeneratePassword = input(Name + " would you like to generate a random password? ")
        YesOptions = ["Yes", "yes", "Y", "y"]
        NoOptions = ["No", "no", "N", "n"]
        PasswordCharacters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        while GeneratePassword in YesOptions:
            Password =  "".join(random.choice(PasswordCharacters) for i in range(random.randint(8, 16)))
            print(Password)
            GeneratePasswordAgain = input("Would you like to generate another random password? ")
            while GeneratePasswordAgain in YesOptions:
                Password =  "".join(random.choice(PasswordCharacters) for i in range(random.randint(8, 16)))
                print(Password)
                GeneratePasswordAgain = input("Would you like to generate another random password? ")
                break
            while GeneratePasswordAgain in NoOptions:
                print("Good bye!")
                sys.exit()
                break
            while GeneratePasswordAgain not in YesOptions or NoOptions:
                print("Not a valid response! Try again.")
                GeneratePasswordAgain = input("Would you like to generate another random password? ")
                break
        while GeneratePassword in NoOptions:
            print("Good bye!")
            sys.exit()
        while GeneratePassword not in YesOptions or NoOptions:
            print("Not a valid response! Try again.")
            PasswordGenerator()
            while GeneratePassword in YesOptions:
                Password =  "".join(random.choice(PasswordCharacters) for i in range(random.randint(8, 16)))
                print(Password)
                GeneratePasswordAgain = input("Would you like to generate another random password? ")
                while GeneratePasswordAgain in YesOptions:
                    Password =  "".join(random.choice(PasswordCharacters) for i in range(random.randint(8, 16)))
                    print(Password)
                    break
                    GeneratePasswordAgain = input("Would you like to generate another random password? ")
                while GeneratePasswordAgain in NoOptions:
                    print("Good bye!")
                    sys.exit()
                    break
                while GeneratePasswordAgain not in YesOptions or NoOptions:
                    print("Not a valid response! Try again.")
                    GeneratePasswordAgain = input("Would you like to generate another random password? ")
                    break
        while GeneratePassword in NoOptions:
            print("Good bye!")
            sys.exit()
    while Name is not Name.isalpha:
        print("Not a valid response! Try again.")
        PasswordGenerator()

PasswordGenerator()
```

Comment: Why does the program for the user name at all? Why does it matter if the user name is "Martin", "Joe123" or ""?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a bug. If the initial response to "Do you want to..." is neither yes-like or no-like, it prompts for the username again. Also, you have large sections of dead code that will never execute.

1. **Avoid duplicating code.**

   Several prompts are exactly the same as each other, even with the same logic after them. Refactor the code so that each possibility only occurs once.
2. **Avoid duplicating variables**

   The `GeneratePassword` and `GeneratePasswordAgain` variables serve the same purpose: to get user input and determine if it should continue. and should be unified.
3. **Keep the code reusable.**

   Avoid calls like `sys.exit()` that prevent this snippet of code from being used elsewhere.
4. **Use the language features properly.**

   You know how to use `while` loops -- so why are you making multiple unnecessary recursive calls, each of which performs the same task as a `while` loop?
5. **Separate logic and user-interface. Separate the code into modules.**

   Write the function that generates the password and does nothing else. Something like

   ```
    def RandomPassword(passwordCharacters, minLetters, maxLetters):
       return "".join(random.choice(PasswordCharacters) for i in range(random.randint(minLetters, maxLetters)))

    def DefaultRandomPassword():
        passwordCharacters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        return RandomPassword(passwordCharacters, 8, 16)
   ```

   Write another function that takes a prompt, displays it, waits for the user to type something, and then does it again if it was not a valid yes-no answer. Then return either yes or no. Call this function multiple times.

Comment: When I don't use `sys.exit()` in while `GeneratePassword in NoOptions:` the `while GeneratePassword not in YesOptions and NoOptions:` snippet is executed though.

Comment: Then that's another bug. Hint: What do you intend to accomplish with `GeneratePassword not in YesOptions and NoOptions` clause? What is the order of operations? What is the effect of using `and` between two lists?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Snowbody's answer, I'd like to point out that `random.choice` and `random.randint` are *not* fit for generating passwords. The `random` module makes use of the Mersenne Twister, which is [not cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Disadvantages). The Python 3.6 release added [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) to the standard library, which retrieves random data from `/dev/urandom`. If you're not running Python 3.6 or upwards, you can still use [`random.SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) (or [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) directly).

---

Also, have a close look at [this xkcd post](https://www.xkcd.com/936/) :)

Answer (score 4):

1. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): Top-level functions should be surrounded by [two blank lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines). [CamelCase](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) names are usually for classes. Functions and variables should be in [lower_case_with_underscores](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names). Limit all lines to a maximum of [79](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) characters.
2. Instead of `PasswordGenerator()` in the end of your script write this:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       PasswordGenerator()
   ```

   You can read about it for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).
3. If you have python3.6 then you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals):

   ```
   GeneratePassword = input(f"{Name} would you like to generate a random password? ")
   ```
4. You have some [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) in your code. How about taking them to function's signature? We also could take there `YesOptions` and `NoOptions` and use [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). After all, [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python).
5. Instead of using `i` variables in your loops use `_`. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python).
6. `sys.exit()` is too extreme. Use `return` instead.
7. Some lines of your code that go after `sys.exit()` and `break` are unreachable.
8. All this spaghetti code with recursions can be rewritten in a much clearer way. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response/23294659#23294659) answer about asking user for a valid response.

In the end it can be something like this:

```
import random
import string
from typing import Set


def generate_passwords(*,
                       min_length: int = 8,
                       max_length: int = 16,
                       password_characters: str = (string.ascii_letters
                                                   + string.digits
                                                   + string.punctuation)
                       ) -> None:
    username = ask_name()

    question = f'{username} would you like to generate a random password? '
    while True:
        if user_wants_password(question):
            password_length = random.randint(min_length, max_length)
            password = ''.join(random.choice(password_characters)
                               for _ in range(password_length))
            print(password)

            question = 'Would you like to generate another random password? '
            continue

        print('Good bye!')
        return


def ask_name() -> str:
    while True:
        username = input('What is your name? ')
        if username.isalpha():
            return username
        print('Not a valid response! Try again.')


def user_wants_password(question: str,
                        *,
                        yes_options: Set[str] = {'Yes', 'yes', 'Y', 'y'},
                        no_options: Set[str] = {'No', 'no', 'N', 'n'}) -> bool:
    while True:
        response = input(question)
        if response in yes_options:
            return True
        elif response in no_options:
            return False
        else:
            print('Not a valid response! Try again.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_passwords()
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) (I'd change the loop-statement in `ask_name()` to just `if username.isalpha():
            
        return username
print('Not a valid response! Try again.')`.)